# Error for editText setOnFocusChangeListener

Tags: java, android

Trying to use setOnFocusChangeListener by

```
mMessageBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

but when I use this function in onCreate function eclipse gives error as

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new 
     OnFocusChangeListener(){})
    - OnFocusChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type
```

Is it because of the minimum sdk that I use in manifest file ? My sdk options in manifest file is

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler already says it

```
new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
...
}
```

Emphasis is on `View`.